# MAKE_INTERVAL Syntax

Tags: postgresql

I just found out that using <= throws an error: SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "days" does not exist

So why is this valid

```
MAKE_INTERVAL(DAYS => 5)
```

and this isn't?

```
MAKE_INTERVAL(DAYS <= 5)
```

Is it maybe a postgres bug?

Comment: `days => 5` means "call this function with the parameter `days` set to 5". See [the documenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CALLING-FUNCS-NAMED) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the operator to provide a [named parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CALLING-FUNCS-NAMED) is `=>` and thus `days` in the first example refers to a function parameter with that name.

`<=` in the second example is seen as the "smaller than or equal operator" and thus Postgres expects that `days` is a column reference.